# Marketing Cloud : What is the correct Subscriber status for 'bounced' emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber

I am trying to mass update a list of imported subscribers in Marketing Cloud to set their Status "Bounced".

According to the [Salesforce MC Subscriber doc](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/subscribers1/) the correct status is indeed "Bounced" (colour status yellow), however I get an "InvalidContextStatus" error for all contacts set to status of "Bounced" in my log after running the subscriber update.

Can someone confirm what the correct value should be?

Comment: I have been told previously that the only two statuses users are allowed to manually change are either 'Active' or 'Unsubscribed'.  I would recommend putting in a SFMC support ticket as well - there may be something that they can do on their end to allow this.

Comment: A bounced status really only matters in the context of when the last bounce (or bounces) occurred for that subscriber and what type of bounce it was. Uploading as 'Bounced' doesn't provide any of that information. Is there any reason why you can't set that as either Active or Unsubscribed?